# Select distinct values from the multiple columns one has many values

Tags: sql, mysql

I have table in this format:

| plan_Id | plan_CD | plan_ASSO |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 2 | A-2-41557-425898 |
| 2 | 2 | A-2-41559-425939_H |
| 2 | 2 | A-2-41560-425939_H |
| 2 | 2 | A-2-41561-425894 |
| 2 | 2 | A-2-41563-425932 |
| 2 | 2 | A-2-41564-425932 |
| 3 | 3 | A-3-76909-425899 |
| 3 | 3 | A-3-76909-425899_H |
| 4 | 4 | A-4-41489-425967 |
| 4 | 4 | A-4-41524-425967 |

How to get the result in this format

| plan_Id | plan_CD | plan_ASSO |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 2 | A-2-41557-425898 |
| 3 | 3 | A-3-76909-425899 |
| 4 | 4 | A-4-41489-425967 |

I want to replace `plan_ASSO` field value `A-2-41557-425898` instead of 2 with `xx`.

Comment: If it's always `_H` you could also use `REPLACE(plan_ASSO, '_H', '')`

Comment: What's the logic to select for example A-2-41557-425898 for plan_Id 2 and not A-2-41561-425894?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1313120/retrieving-the-last-record-in-each-group-mysql?rq=1

Comment: please explain your Problem it doesnt minimums of "question" in the overflow stack are not met https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Don't see logic, what about  A-2-41561-425894 or A-2-41559-425939_H ? Don't understand what means "I want to replace plan_ASSO field value A-2-41557-425898 instead of 2 with xx."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you want to replace the `plan_Id` value in the `plan_ASSO` field with "xx" in the result. You can achieve this using the `CONCAT` function in MySQL along with a `CASE` statement to conditionally modify the `plan_ASSO` field. Here's the SQL query that should give you the desired result:

```sql
SELECT
    plan_Id,
    plan_CD,
    CASE
        WHEN plan_ASSO LIKE 'A-%-%-%' THEN CONCAT('A-xx-', SUBSTRING(plan_ASSO, 7))
        ELSE plan_ASSO
    END AS plan_ASSO
FROM
    your_table
GROUP BY
    plan_Id, plan_CD, plan_ASSO
ORDER BY
    plan_Id;
```

Make sure to replace `your_table` with the actual name of your table. This query will replace the `plan_Id` value in the `plan_ASSO` field with "xx" for rows where the `plan_ASSO` starts with "A-". For other rows, it will keep the original `plan_ASSO` value. The `GROUP BY` clause ensures that you get unique rows for each `plan_Id`, `plan_CD`, and modified `plan_ASSO` combination.